# VSC Extension calls a python script which depends on a Config.txt file. The script can't find the config.txt when called from the command palette

Tags: javascript, python, vscode-extensions

I am building simple VSC Extension that is able to run a python script when I enter a command in the command palette.
The python script reads certain data from a config.txt file located in the same directory as the script.

**My issue is:** When I run the script from the terminal, it is able to locate the config file. When I run it through the command palette however, the config file can't be located.

**os.getcwd()**  -> returns the path that I expect when I run the script from a terminal.
When I run it from the command palette it however, the path it returns is **/home/user**.

Is there a way to make the file path of the config.txt file into a configuration for the extension itself?
How would I then add this configuration item to the python script

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Note: The extension is not only going to be used by me so hardcoding the path sadly isn't an option

Comment: isn't a "config.txt" the _settings_ for your extension that contains default settings? If so, the content belongs in the [_settings_](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration)

Comment: Can you share your code?